# How do I explicitly order query results when using UNION?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, union

I am trying to order my query results in the order below and i am receiving this error message.

'ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator'

```
SELECT [Category]
FROM [dbo].[Category]
WHERE LOWER([Category]) LIKE '%yearling%' OR LOWER([Category]) LIKE '%foal%' OR LOWER([Category]) LIKE '%in%utero%'
    UNION
SELECT [AcquisitionType] AS 'Category'
FROM [dbo].[AcquisitionType]
WHERE LOWER([AcquisitionType]) LIKE '%homebred%'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Category] = 'In Utero' THEN 1
              WHEN [Category] = 'In Utero & FS' THEN 2
              WHEN [Category] = 'FS in Utero' THEN 3
              WHEN [Category] = 'Foal' THEN 4
              WHEN [Category] = 'Foal & FS' THEN 5
              WHEN [Category] = 'FS Foal' THEN 6
              WHEN [Category] = 'Yearling' THEN 7
              WHEN [Category] = 'Yearling & FS' THEN 8
              WHEN [Category] = 'FS Yearling' THEN 9
              WHEN [Category] = 'N/a' THEN 10
              ELSE [Category] END ASC
```

I would like the results to return in the order they are listed in the query.

How do I do that?

I'm a bit lost on this one so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Wrap the query in an outer select and order.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery or CTE:

```
SELECT Category
FROM (SELECT [Category]
      FROM [dbo].[Category]
      WHERE LOWER([Category]) LIKE '%yearling%' OR LOWER([Category]) LIKE '%foal%' OR LOWER([Category]) LIKE '%in%utero%'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT [AcquisitionType] AS Category
      FROM [dbo].[AcquisitionType]
      WHERE LOWER([AcquisitionType]) LIKE '%homebred%'
     ) c
ORDER BY . . .;
```

Notice that I replaced the `UNION` with `UNION ALL`.  `UNION` incurs overhead to remove duplicates.

Based on the logic, your two subqueries cannot have duplicates between them.  So, there is no need to remove duplicates unless each subquery might have duplicates.  If so, I would recommend `SELECT DISTINCT` rather than a `UNION` query.